# iCloud emails are automatically marked read without any notification

Tags: icloud

For years the emails that I received on my iCloud mail account were marked instantly as read without receiving any notification. I have tried using other mail apps with no success. I have turned on notifications on all devices and I receive emails from other email accounts. I also don’t have rules or forwarding enabled.

It’s been a couple of days. The support and I tried most likely everything with my devices to fix the issue with no success.
I have done a little digging and found out that I receive emails with the following flag `X-Apple-Flags \Seen`. After testing with a working iCloud account this flag only shows up if a `Mark a read`-rule is enabled on iCloud.com. In the past, I had such a rule enabled but not anymore. So I think Apple's Mailserver has a bug that led to it still using the rule even when I deleted it.

The iCloud engineering team has confirmed that this is most likely a previously deleted rule that is stuck.

Comment: Are these emails going directly to your iCloud account or are they being forwarded or retrieved from another account into your iCloud account?

Comment: There going directly to the iCloud account. I had a call with the support and even they didn’t know what’s going on. I have a call with them on the 16th after the higher ups look at the problem.

Comment: They would be in the best position to see what's happening, then.  That said, instead of using a mail client (like Mail), check your mail from your browser.  Are they being marked as read there as well?

Comment: Yea. We checked everywhere. Mail app, iCloud.com, and a third party app. We turned off devices and networks. It’s always the same behaviour.

Comment: If you disable using the icloud mail app temorarily, will the emails still always be marked as read?

Comment: yes. Current state of the problem is that it's a very unique problem. I send the support a ton of logs of my devices and they are currently looking at it. I will update this problem over the next days/weeks until there is a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

So after 3 weeks i got it fixed.

The problem was a mail service/server issue on apples side. Somehow my deleted rules got stuck on their end and there was nothing I could about.

If someone has this problem check the X-Apple- entries in headers of your mails, since these are set by apples servers.